# Django E.408, E.409 and E.410 errors on runserver

Tags: python, django

現在、djangoでウェbサイトの開発を勉強している大学生です。コマンドプロンプトで「python manage.py runserver」と書いたところ、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

?: (admin.E408)'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E409) 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E410) 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.

どうすればよいか全く分からず途方に暮れています。是非プロフェッショナルの皆様方の力を貸していただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: どこの Tutorial に従ってどこまで作業しているとかの情報があると答えが得られやすいのでは？ 例えば [はじめての Django アプリ作成、その 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) とか。あと動作させている環境(OSとかツールとかファイル/フォルダ構成など)が何かといった情報もあれば助けになるでしょう。

Comment: 承認が付いていませんが、この記事 [Django E.408, E.409 and E.410 errors on runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56923576/9014308) が参考になるかも。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.pyの MIDDLEWAREの順番を確認してください。

おそらく、AuthenticationMiddleware、MessageMiddleware、SessionMiddlewareを設定すれば治ると思います。